# get field values from dynamic table to be saved in localStorage - html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamic table created and need to save it in the `localStorage`. I have two problems.

1. when I add a first row - it doesn't show values in the `console`. But it displays when I add a row second time.
2. I need to save all the fields like :
   *(fname1, lname1, phone1, email1, 
   fname2, lanem2, phone2, email2,
   fname3, lname3, phone3, email3)*

Bellow is the code:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('dynTable'),
    tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0],
    clone = tbody.rows[0].cloneNode(true);

function deleteRow(el) {
    var i = el.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    table.deleteRow(i);
    while (table.rows[i]) {
        addRow(table.rows[i], i, false);
        i++;
    }
}

function insRow() {
    var new_row = addRow(clone.cloneNode(true), ++tbody.rows.length, true);
    tbody.appendChild(new_row);
}

function addRow(row, i, reset) {
    var F_Name = row.cells[0].innerHTML = i;
    var L_Name = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    var Phone = row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
 var Email = row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

 Number = 'Number' + i;
    F_Name.id = 'F_Name' + i;
    L_Name.id = 'L_Name' + i;
 Phone.id = 'Phone' + i;
 Email.id = 'Email' + i;

    return row;
}

    function save() {
        var myTab = document.getElementById('dynTable');
        var myArray = new Array();

  var rowLength = myTab.rows.length - 1;
  
        for (row = 1; row < rowLength; row++) {
         for (c = 0; c < 5; c++) {   // EACH CELL IN A ROW.
                var element = myTab.rows.item(row).cells[c];
                   var curtext = myArray.push("'" + element.childNodes[0].value + "'");
            }
  }
 //   var mylocalVar = localStorage.setItem("rowData", myArray);
  console.log(myArray);
    }
```

```html
<form action="dynamicTable.html" method="get" >
    <table id="dynTable" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
    <td></td>
                <td>F_Name</td>
                <td>L_Name</td>
                <td>Phone</td>
                <td>Email</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="F_Name" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="L_Name" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="Phone" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="Email" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="addmore" value="Add More" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="Save" onclick="save()" />

</form>
```

Comment: In your code, I can not find where you store data in `localStorage`?

Comment: @ Keyur Ramoliya - i have not stored yet. First i need to see it in the console. Sorry that it confused you. I need the every row as a row set in the console in every loop. It's all combined in one array. I need to separate them as rows data. Thanks.

Comment: @Keyur Ramoliya - i get error to see the localStorage variable in the snippet, but we could see it in the browser

Comment: What error exactly you get on that line? It probably due to you are storing an array in `localStorage`.

Comment: my question is not about localStorage, it's about how i could retrieve each row from javascript which I need help . Before answering to the question please Run the code snippet if it's available. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, There is a problem in your logic. In save logic, you are starting from the first index in the table and does not iterate to even first index. So it should be like this `for (row = 1; row <= rowLength; row++)`.

See below working snippet:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('dynTable'),
  tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0],
  clone = tbody.rows[0].cloneNode(true);

function deleteRow(el) {
  var i = el.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  table.deleteRow(i);
  while (table.rows[i]) {
    addRow(table.rows[i], i, false);
    i++;
  }
}

function insRow() {
  var new_row = addRow(clone.cloneNode(true), ++tbody.rows.length, true);
  tbody.appendChild(new_row);
}

function addRow(row, i, reset) {
  var F_Name = row.cells[0].innerHTML = i;
  var L_Name = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  var Phone = row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  var Email = row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

  Number = 'Number' + i;
  F_Name.id = 'F_Name' + i;
  L_Name.id = 'L_Name' + i;
  Phone.id = 'Phone' + i;
  Email.id = 'Email' + i;

  return row;
}

function save() {
  var myTab = document.getElementById('dynTable');
  var myArray = new Array();

  var rowLength = myTab.rows.length - 1;

  for (row = 1; row <= rowLength; row++) {
    for (c = 0; c < 5; c++) { // EACH CELL IN A ROW.
      var element = myTab.rows.item(row).cells[c];
      var curtext = myArray.push("'" + element.childNodes[0].value + "'");
    }
  }
  //   var mylocalVar = localStorage.setItem("rowData", myArray);
  console.log(myArray);
}
```

```html
<form action="dynamicTable.html" method="get">
  <table id="dynTable" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>F_Name</td>
        <td>L_Name</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>Email</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="F_Name" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="L_Name" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Phone" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Email" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="addmore" value="Add More" onclick="insRow()" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Save" onclick="save()" />

</form>
```

Comment: Hi @Keyur Ramoliya, thanks for your help to resolve my first question. I did get to work on my second question too by myself!